# Are there any known implementations of IBIndingList that support the Find method, suitable for LINQ?

Tags: linq, data-binding, bindingsource

It seems as if only *DataSet*, *DataTable* and *DataView* can be used as sources when you want to use `BindingSource.Find`. I'm binding *IQueryable* and *IEnumerable* to my binding source, but would very much like to enjoy the 'convenience' of the `BindingSource.Find` method, without writing reams of code myself, as time is of the essence.

Does anyone know of an existing implementation, or at least detailed 'how to' article that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) and [Array.FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy.aspx) methods to create a concise extension method.

```
public static int Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string propertyName, Object key)
{
    PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if(property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Type {0} contains no property named \"{1}\". ",
                                    typeof(T).Name, propertyName), "propertyName");
    }
    return Array.FindIndex(items.ToArray(), i => Object.Equals(property.GetValue(i, null), key));       
}
```